# c shell script doesn't exit

Tags: perl, csh

I have a perl script that calls a c shell script. 
something along the lines of

```
 system($cmd)
```

$cmd contains some c-shell scirpt, which does the following:

```
some_task1 &
set task1_id = $!
sleep 300s &
set task2_id = $!

while (`ps -p "$task1_id,$task2_id" | wc -l` > 2)
     sleep 1m
end

# assume of the moment that task2 will finish first
kill -9 $task1_id 
exit
```

I expect that the process task1_id will be terminated and that the c-shell script will finish and return control to the calling perl script once

```
sleep 300s
```

is done.

however, what actually happens is that after

```
exit
```

control never returns to the calling script. How do I make sure that nested scripts actually returns?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to run the `sleep` command in the background? That seems to defeat the purpose of running the other task in the background and then killing it later.

Comment: Yes, I did.The idea is that there's a task and a timeout timer. There's a while loop that "sleeps" for a short interval while both task and timer are running. When the while loop is done,  whoever finishes first, kills the other, reports and exits.

Comment: So your shell script looks nothing like what you've put in your question?

Comment: I thought I provided the pertinent details. Question has been edited to reflect your comment.

Comment: the best thing you can do is to add `echo "before exit" .... echo "after exit"` sort of debugging to your csh code to see what is really going on. And you can use `#!/bin/csh -fbvx` to turn on debug/trace (I forget what `-fb` does anymore, but we always used that as well, but check your `csh` man page to confirm). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Timeout**

One method to return to the calling Perl script is to call the csh script within a timed out call. The trade off is that the csh script will be aborted after reaching the timeout.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use strict;
use Sys::SigAction qw(timeout_call);

my $cmd = 'sleep 5';
my $timeout = 2;
if (timeout_call($timeout, sub {
  my $out = system($cmd);
})) {
  print "command '$cmd' runs into timeout after $timeout s\n";
}
```

**Threads**

Another approach is to encapsulate each task in a system call within a thread. This is a very simple example that does not consider any timeouts. Detached threads will live on after the Perl script has finished and will be assigned to PPID 1.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use strict;
use threads;

my $task1 = threads->new(sub { 
  print "start task1\n"; qx(sleep 2); print "stop task1\n"; return 
});
my $task2 = threads->new(sub {
  print "task2\n"; qx(sleep 1); print "stop task2\n"; return 
});

$task2->join();
$task1->detach();
print "Detach task1\n";
```